# how to convert set of dictionaries to a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to convert my individual separate dictionaries into a list of dictionaries

this is my current dictionary:

```
order = {'company_name': 'FRIENDS',  'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.37315509207642000000', 'longitude': '103.76570152476201000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-12-06', 'region': 'WEST'}
{'company_name': 'FLOWERS', 'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.28821802835873000000', 'longitude': '103.84569230314800000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-11-29', 'region': 'CENTRAL'}
{'company_name': 'SUNSHINE',  'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.37414901860683000000', 'longitude': '103.94353973518100000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-11-08', 'region': 'EAST'}
{'company_name': 'CLOUDS', 'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.39663901543996000000', 'longitude': '103.81937713764700000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-25', 'region': 'NORTH'}
{'company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH'}
```

this is my intended output:

```
order = [{'company_name': 'FRIENDS',  'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.37315509207642000000', 'longitude': '103.76570152476201000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-12-06', 'region': 'WEST'},
{'company_name': 'FLOWERS', 'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.28821802835873000000', 'longitude': '103.84569230314800000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-11-29', 'region': 'CENTRAL'},
{'company_name': 'SUNSHINE',  'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.37414901860683000000', 'longitude': '103.94353973518100000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-11-08', 'region': 'EAST'},
{'company_name': 'CLOUDS', 'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.39663901543996000000', 'longitude': '103.81937713764700000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-25', 'region': 'NORTH'},
{'company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH'}]
```

i have tried:

```
neworder = list(order.items())
```

but this only returns one dataset

```
[('company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH')]
```

then i tried a loop:

```
for i in order:
    neworder = list(order.items()) 
    print(neworder)
```

but it still only returns 1 dataset and multiple lists

```
[('company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH')]
[('company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH')]
[('company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH')]
[('company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH')]
[('company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH')]
[('company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH')]
[('company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH')]
[('company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH')]
```

Comment: `order` is not a list. It is a single dictionary; the other rows are discarded. Surround everything with `[...]` or `list(...)` to make it a list.

Comment: @Amadan I have tried 

`neworder = [order]
print(neworder)`

but my output is still just 1 dataset. 

`[{'company_name': 'SUN', 'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.39663901543996000000', 'longitude': '103.81937713764700000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-25', 'region': 'NORTH'}]`

how do I get all of the data out into a list of dictionaries? do I need to loop it?

Comment: Imagine you have 10 eggs on the table, and you want to remove the tablecloth; you pick up one egg, then whip the tablecloth off the table. You end up with one egg safely in your hand, and a mess on the floor. Asking "how to get my eggs back" is misguided - you should have put all the eggs in a cardboard box, then lifted the box in the first place. You do _not have_ a list of dictionaries. You have a single dictionary, and a mess on the floor.

Comment: @Tessa Try doing `print(order)` immediately after you create it, and you will see that it only contains the contents of the first line.

Answer (score 1):

from where do you get your set of dictionaries, if you are initializing order in you code like this then you have only assigned 1st dictionary to order other are not assigned to any variable. you should wrap the dictionaries inside "[ ]" and add commas like below

```py
order = [
    {'company_name': 'FRIENDS',  'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.37315509207642000000', 'longitude': '103.76570152476201000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-12-06', 'region': 'WEST'}
    {'company_name': 'FLOWERS', 'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.28821802835873000000', 'longitude': '103.84569230314800000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-11-29', 'region': 'CENTRAL'},
    {'company_name': 'SUNSHINE',  'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.37414901860683000000', 'longitude': '103.94353973518100000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-11-08', 'region': 'EAST'},
    {'company_name': 'CLOUDS', 'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.39663901543996000000', 'longitude': '103.81937713764700000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-25', 'region': 'NORTH'},
    {'company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH'}
]
```

Comment: I don't want to manually input them in, how can I then run a code where it sorts it out by itself?

Comment: you can use find in replace in IDE, find: "}" and replace with "},". if you have lots of such files then you can write python script to do that

Comment: reason being I have hundreds of datasets. "order" is just a small sample of what it is. to manually input [] & , would be very tedious

Comment: Inputting `[` and `]` is two characters: that is not "tedious" by any definition. Adding a comma to each line can be automated in any sane editor (i.e. not Notepad). You could also write another program to do it for you - that's what being a programmer is all about. But there is nothing you can do within _this_ program to fix it.